# Changing name of json attribute in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I change the name of a json field response given by the serializer from the Django Rest Framework?

After following the [documentation](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html) I tried this, however it didn't work.

```
from api.models import Countries
from rest_framework import serializers

class CountrySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    country_geoname_id = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    iso = serializers.CharField(max_length=2L, required=True)
    country_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=64L, required=True)

    def transform_iso(self, obj, value):
        return "country_code"
```

Basically the JSON response looks like this:

```
{
    "country_geoname_id": 3041565, 
    "iso": "AD", 
    "country_name": "Andorra"
},
```

And I am trying to change the field `iso` to `country_code`.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem is. Why not just call the field `country_code`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `source` attribute on the field.

See:
http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#core-arguments

So with your example you would do:

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    country_geoname_id = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    country_code = serializers.CharField(source='iso', max_length=2L, required=True)
    country_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=64L, required=True)
```

Hope this helps you.